# Which driver/file ( deb or rpm ) should I download for printing and how to install it?

Tags: drivers, printing, crunchbang, canon

I would like to ask which driver/file ( deb or rpm ) I should download for printing and how to install it on Crunchbang?

[Canon PIXMA MG2450](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg2450.aspx?type=download&language=EN&os=Linux)

First I tried to try out System > Printers> Install printing support but even though it seems as if it is installing at the beginning, It stops proceeding and says :

```
There was a problem installing printing packets.
```

And then I check out Canon's official website for drivers but but this time I am confused which driver I should download and how to install it.

And after I've read a few blogs about that I decided to try out the deriver which contains files with .deb because Crunchbang is based on debian.

I run this "codes"

```
cd downloads

cd printer
```

( I changed the original name of the folder I downloaded cos it was not convenient. )

```
bash install.sh
```

But even though the driver was installed, Crunchbang was failed to detect my printer.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2210668

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Thanks .Actually I had read the thread before I submitted this question.But even though I managed to install the driver at the end , in the terminal crunchbang could not detect my printer and I read on a different blogs that it  says the reason for not recognizing printers varies . Do you think can we do something to get my printer recognize

Comment: i found some other threads (with further links): http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2232486 or http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/installation-canon-pixma-mg2450/ (german) -- have you tried to use some different USB-ports (with different controllers)?!?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Thank you for your help.I managed to install it by help this site : https://wiki.debian.org/SystemPrinting

Comment: maybe you can write an answer for some others facing the same problems...?